# How to generate GeoJson data to make a choropleth map on Leaflet?

Tags: java, leaflet, visualization, geojson, choropleth

I want to make a choropleth map like so - https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ , using data from the Indian HIV statistics fact sheet. I am very new to coding so I am unsure how to proceed. I have the in xcl format for the HIV stats, and I know I can get India-specific GeoJson data somewhere on github. But I don't know how I can proceed further with this. I need to know how to go about it.

I found Indian GeoJson data on github. I also generated the HIV stats in xcl format. I tried and tested the example map in the Leaflet site I linked above, but got stuck in the color function step. Given how new I am to this, I didn't do too much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.